# footer to stay in view and content scroll behinds?

Tags: html, css

How can I make it so `item2` blue box is always visible at the bottom of the page and any content would scroll behind this?

[JSFiddle with added content](https://jsfiddle.net/9g45synm/)

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 80%;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 20%;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">
    <!-- content here -->
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove **height: 80%** for item1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the property of `.flex-container` is doing the issue. Usually if you want to have a `div` or footer on bottom you allign it with `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;` while your parent `div` gets `position: relative;`.

This way your footer will be always on the bottom of the screen, all you need to do is to give the last ellement of your css some `margin-bottom` based on the height of your footer. This way you should not cover any content.

[Read this it will help you.](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)